# Hiding a child form close it instead and return me to the owner c#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a login form and after I validate the user I call the main form with the following code:

```
frmMain frm = new frmMain();
Hide()
frm.ShowDialog();
Show();
```

The problem is when I try to hide the main form with Hide() or Visible = false, to minimize the application to the tray bar, the main form gets closed and the application returns me to the login form like if I press the close button.

How does `Hide()` and `Show()` work? Does it create another instance?

Comment: You can display login form first: `formLogin.ShowDialog();` and then `mainForm.ShowDialog();` instead of playing with visibility. Otherwise your questions is not full: how exactly do you minimize **application** to the tray bar, how do you restore, what happens and what you expect to happens instead? Description *"the main form get closed and the application returns me to the login form like if i press the close button"* doesn't explain the problem clearly.

Comment: Hiding a dialog will always close it.  You must use Show() instead.  Consider using the main form's FormClosing event to make it visible again.

Answer (score 1):

When a modal form is hidden, it would return to the calling code. That's how it is. What i would do is change the code to either close the login form after showing the main form:

```
frmMain frm = new frmMain();
frm.Show();
Close()
```

If you want to show again the login form when the main form is closed, you could use the `FormClosing` event, like this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    frmLogin frmlogin= new frmLogin();
    frmlogin.Show();
}
```

Or call the main form in the beginning, and from it call the login form as a dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Make two window form, 1:- Login (default open), 2:- Main (Open on login success)

1:- First login window will open
2:- after successfully login close/hide the login form and open/show the Main form which will also be window.
3:- handle the task bar display property in the same way.